# How to attribute values to a group according to dataset information

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I need a dummy variable to identify the mothers whose children have High IQ, whereas this question is not directly asked.

I'm no quite familiar with R, thus my question might be simple. This is the data used:

```
data <- data.frame(family=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  position=c("mother","son","father",
                         "mother","son","father",
                         "mother","son","son","son"),
              sex=c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0),
              highiq=c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0))
```

Where *family* tells which observations compose a family group, *positions* informs the individual's position in the family, *sex* it's sex and *highiq* is equal to 1 when the observation shows a High IQ. I've already managed to identify sons with a high IQ by:

```
dat2 <- dat%>%
  mutate(high.son = position=="son"& highiq==1)
```

But I can't go further. I imagine a possible solution would be to create a dummy variable for mothers (is.mother), and another dummy variable that attributes 1 to every member of the family in which at least one son has High IQ (IQ.family)-if the family has no sons with a high IQ, then they all get 0-, and then multiply the *is.mother* dummy variable by this new *IQ.family* variable, for what we should get only mothers with high IQ sons.

One problem I had with this strategy was that i couldn't generate the variable *IQ.family*, because i can't find a way to attribute values to a group according others informations of the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`any(highiq[position == 'son'] == 1)` is `TRUE` if `highIQ == 1` for any son. So you need to assign that value to the new variable if `position == 'mother'`, and assign 0 otherwise.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(family) %>% 
  mutate(mother_highIQ_son = 
           ifelse(position == 'mother', any(highiq[position == 'son'] == 1), 0))

# # A tibble: 10 x 5
# # Groups:   family [3]
#    family position   sex highiq mother_highIQ_son
#     <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>             <dbl>
#  1      1 mother       0      0                 0
#  2      1 son          1      0                 0
#  3      1 father       1      1                 0
#  4      2 mother       0      1                 1
#  5      2 son          0      1                 0
#  6      2 father       1      1                 0
#  7      3 mother       0      0                 1
#  8      3 son          1      0                 0
#  9      3 son          0      1                 0
# 10      3 son          0      0                 0
```

The `== 1` isn't strictly necessary but if it's not included you get a warning about type coercion.

Comment: The 7th obsertvation should also have got a 1, do you know why it hasn't?

Comment: Oops, didn't look at the data closely so didn't consider > 1 son. Should work now that I've added `any`